# R᠎e᠎d᠎u᠎n᠎d᠎ancy

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

[image: puzzle]

Your final answer should answer the question "What is something you could get after solving this puzzle?"

Comment: Got five out of the six, but I really need to sleep... very nice puzzle, though!

Comment: Incredible puzzle!

Comment: This is an incredibly clever puzzle! If I hadn’t joined this stack already I’d join it just to upvote this.

Comment: This is brilliant (+1). Was "redandancy" at the top intentionally spelt that way?

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Yes — see my reply on Duesovi's solution.

Comment: Subtle hint... sublime.

Comment: Wow what a superb puzzle! That must have taken hours to make.

Comment: If only there was a way to award a bonus to a question.

Comment: This is a very good puzzle. Can you add an answer explaining how did you create it? see https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5420/sharing-and-rewarding-what-went-into-making-a-good-puzzle

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Each of these:

> can be made into a word by applying some transformation. The trick to this is that all of the information is used *twice* - the lines drawn are only half of what we actually need.

---

**Left column, top:**

> Reflecting across a diagonal line gives ABSURD.
>  [image]

**Left column, middle:**

> Appending a color-flipped version of the same picture gives FOSSIL.
>  [image]

**Left column, bottom:**

> Overlay a copy shifted to the right, and you can read the word PETROL.
>  [image]

**Right column, top:**

> Overlaying a copy rotated 180° gives BANDIT.
>  [image]

**Right column, middle:**

> Reading the cubes from the front gives BEY; reading the cubes from the right side gives OND.
>  [image]

**Right column, bottom:**

> Overlaying a horizontally reflected copy gives OVERDO.
>  [image]

---

Now what?

> Each of the words had one eye on it in the original image - when the transformation was applied, that eye marked two different letters.
>
>  So that gives us a total of twelve letters - but how do we order them?
>
>  The boxes next to the words, when overlaid, make a shape that looks like a 6:
>
>   [image]
>
>  And one of the shapes looks like a 1...
>
>  This gives the final "redundant" art: There's an order that you can overlay the six shapes, so they look like the numbers 1-6.
>  [image]
>  Picking one of the two eye-marked letters from each word, in this order, gives **DOUBLE** - and the other eye-marked letters give **VISION**! So **DOUBLE VISION** is the final answer, and certainly something you might get after solving this.

Comment: Wow. This puzzle is incredible - never seen anything that uses ambigrams in this way before! Brilliant solve too - very well done :)

Comment: Correct! Just one little additional detail: rot13(Gur qha/qna va gur gvgyr vf gur rknpg fnzr frg bs tylcuf, uvagvat ng gur prageny zrpunavp.)